# AngularJS - $rootScope to share data with other controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a abstract state whose controller get's data from a $resource async.  and put the result in $rootScope.data.

```
.state('stateA', {
    abstract: true, 
    url...
    templateUrl...
    controller: function($rootScope, Resource){
        // Empty data so far
        $rootScope.data = [];

        Resource.query().$promise.then(function(data){
            $rootScope.data = data;
        })
    }
})
```

Inheriting states are supposed to use that data. At the moment when the controllers from these states are resolved the $rootScope has not received yet the data.

When the Resource.query() is resolved in the abstract state controller, it updates the $rootScope.

Data attached to $rootScope async does not $digest? Why controllers that inherit from the abstract state do not see the changes after $rootScope.data is populated? Do I need to $broadcast and $on?

Comment: Post the code of a subcontroller, and tell us where you expect the data to be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you don't need to do any of those things, you just need to make sure your data gets properly updated and your watchers are properly set. on your child states you should do something like.

```
 scope.$watch(function(){return $rootScope.data},function(){

 })
```

this will let your controller know when the data array has been reassign. you can also use watch collection, it depends what type of modifications are you planning to do make to your array. assigning it it will destroy the array and create a new one, with a new address, but adding and removing elements it affects it in a different way. but bottom line you need watchers in this case because you are recreating the array.

other thing is, i really not recommend using rootScope for this purposes this is what services where made for. it might seem an overkill to use a service for this, but most of the time chances are you are also going to need to implement some data manipulation logic. and you'll end up creating a service anyways if you are doing it right

Answer (score 0):

The proper approach is almost always to create a *service* or *factory* for shared data between controllers.